# How can I change the style of CreateTextNode With JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I was coding this morning a simple contact manager, and I found that I can't change the style of the text in JavaScript !
the Problem :

```
function addcontact() {
    var ul = document.getElementById("list");
    var firstname = document.getElementById("input_firstname");
        var lastname = document.getElementById("input_lastname");
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    li.setAttribute('id',firstname.value);
    li.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Firstname:" + firstname.value + ", Lastname: " + lastname.value ));
    ul.appendChild(li);
}
```

> li.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Firstname:" + firstname.value
>   + ", Lastname: " + lastname.value ));

In this line I can't change the style of "Firstname: " . I tried to add some tags but nothing happened!

How can i solve this problem?

Comment: Create separate spans for first name and last name. .classList.add("class_name") will help you to add css style using that class_name

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`document.createTextNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createTextNode) creates a text node without style. For adding a style to some text, you need to add an element which can have a `style` attribute, like `<span>`.

Instead of using

```
li.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Firstname:" + firstname.value + ", Lastname: " + lastname.value ));
```

you may take another element, like span.

```
var span = document.createElement('span');
span.style = ...; // apply your style
span.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Firstname: "));
li.appendChild(span);
li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(firstname.value + ", Lastname: " + lastname.value));
ul.appendChild(li);
```

Comment: Thank You Sir ! and What If I want To add a style for "firstname" and "lastname" ? thank You !

Comment: for more than one `<span>` tag with style, you could mode the `span` variable into a function and hand over text and style and return this node for a later `appendChild`, as above.